# How to update the version in ElasticSearch update query

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have the following query:

```
body = {
  "script": {
    "inline": "ctx._source.is_hidden=false",
    "inline": "ctx._version=100"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "filename": self.filename
    }
  }
}
task_data = self.es.update_by_query(body=body, doc_type='_doc', index='trackingesthistory', wait_for_completion=False)
```

How would I do the above, that is set the version to 100 for all the above documents?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `version_type` to be `external`. I don't recall the exact syntax, but I believe you can put it in your script.

```
body = {
  "script": {
    "
    "inline": "ctx._source.is_hidden=false",
    "inline": "ctx._index.version_type=external",
    "inline": "ctx._version=100"
  },
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "filename": self.filename
    }
  }
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this exact syntax. Something like that should work though.